# "range constraint violation" error when trying to simulate a circuit in VHDL

Tags: integer, vhdl, unsigned, signed, bitvector

I'm new to VHDL and I'm trying to simulate a block as follows:

1. It has four `std_logic_vector` inputs named `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.
   Inputs `a` and `b` are signed numbers and inputs `c` and `d` are
   unsigned numbers.
2. It has four outputs named `u`, `v`, `w` and `x`. Outputs `u` and `v`
   are signed numbers and outputs `w` and `x` are unsigned numbers.
3. The outputs are defined as follows:

   u = a + b

   v = a / 2

   w = c * d

   x = c * 2
4. The internal signals are integers.

I am able to compile both the module and the test bench. The problem I have is that when I try to simulate the circuit the following error message is displayed:

```
ncsim: *E,TRRANGEC: range constraint violation.
          File: ./operator2.vhd, line = 38, pos = 36
         Scope: :inst_operator:$PROCESS_007
          Time: 0 FS + 0
```

As a consequence, the simulator doesn't start. I don't understand how this line could be wrong:

```
x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(sx, 17));
```

I have tried by changing this line with the other ones which do the same and I get the error in the same line. If I delete this line the error is reported in line 37. Could you please give me a hint to find out my error? Below is the code for the module:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity operator2 is
    port(
        a: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        b: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        c: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        d: in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        u: out std_logic_vector(16 downto 0);
        v: out std_logic_vector(14 downto 0);
        w: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        x: out std_logic_vector(16 downto 0)
    );

end entity operator2;

architecture a2 of operator2 is

    signal su: integer;
    signal sv: integer;
    signal sw: integer;
    signal sx: integer;

begin

    --signals affectation
    su <= to_integer(signed(a)) + to_integer(signed(b));
    sv <= to_integer(signed(a)) / 2;
    sw <= to_integer(unsigned(c)) * to_integer(unsigned(d));
    sx <= to_integer(unsigned(c)) * 2;

    --outputs affectation
    u <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(su, 17));
    v <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(sv, 15));
    w <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(sw, 32));
    x <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(sx, 17)); --This is the line reporting the error during the simulation**

end architecture a2;
```

Comment: Either initialize `sw` and `sx` to values within natural'left and natural'right inclusive or defined them as type natural: `signal sw: natural;  signal sx: natural;`. The issue is the default value for `sw` and `sx` are outside the bounds of a natural for the `to_unsigned` conversion. Note that w(31) will always be '0'.

Comment: @user1155120 : are you sure that w(31) will always be '0', given (say) c = d = x"ffff" ( both valid 16-bit unsigned values)?

Comment: `sw` as an integer can only supply 31 bits (natural range) to an unsigned.  A negative number gives the bounds check failure we see here. (And all this assumes an integer has the minimum guaranteed range  –2147483647 to +2147483647, which is universal among common simulators. A positive number can only be 31 bits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are working with integer values, you should initialize their values. In your signals (su, sv, sw and sx) you have to do that because they are integer values (from -2^31 to 2^31). 
Please try :

```
signal su: integer :=0;
signal sv: integer :=0;
signal sw: integer :=0;
signal sx: integer :=0;
```

if you don't initialize them, they will take the highest value (2^31) so that may cause problems during the simulation.

Answer (score 1):

Line 37 is the error : the maximum range for a natural in VHDL is 31 bits (because natural is the non-negative subset of integer range) so `to_unsigned` with a 32-bit range is ... problematic (informally, David will probably be along soon with the LRM references). Why your simulator reports it on the wrong line, I can't answer. GHDL reports "error: bound check failure at operator2.vhd:37" as expected.

Note that the REAL problem is this line:

```
 sw <= to_integer(unsigned(c)) * to_integer(unsigned(d));
```

which tries to stuff the product of two 16-bit unsigneds into an integer with a 31-bit positive range, which ... doesn't always work.

I suggest making "sw" a 32-bit unsigned not an integer, which will handle the full range correctly.

I'd consider doing the same for the other internal signals for clarity. There is no need to do so on numerical range basis, but if you're keeping them as "integer" it would be better to refine their declarations to make the design intent clear:

```
signal sx: integer;                   -- obscures the design
signal sx: natural range 0 to 131071; -- documents the intent
```

and if you'd done this you'd probably have seen the problem faster.

And as pointed out in the comments, using `natural` rather than `integer` gives a valid default value (`natural'left` = 0) rather than one that cannot be converted to `unsigned` (`integer'left` = -2**31)

Alternatively, provide guarantees on its inputs (C and D) - IF you can restrict at least one of them to 15 bits - that will work too.

I would go further and declare all the ports of the correct type, `signed` or `unsigned` as appropriate, and eliminate most of the unnecessary type conversions that don't do anything for readability. That would also eliminate the internal signals completely, for a considerably less verbose design.

Comment: His simulator reports the correct line, just not the first of the two. (Line 37 has a bounds error as well, the result of the default values for sw and sx, and if you must have a reference: IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.4.2.3 "In the absence of an explicit default expression, an implicit default value is assumed for a signal of a scalar subtype or for each scalar subelement of a composite signal, each of which is itself a signal of a scalar subtype. The implicit default value for a signal of a scalar subtype T is defined to be that given by T'LEFT." Out of bounds for to_unsigned.

Comment: And understanding why the default value is used 14.7.5.2 Initialization. Updating signal values during initialization will cause processes to execute until suspension (and all concurrent statements are elaborated into combinations of processes (as here) or processes and block statements).  INTEGER'LEFT is out of bounds for type NATURAL (used in the to_unsigned parameter).